# Customize storyboards bundled inside iOS Framework file

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, xcode7

I have a framework which has storyboard and xib files.
How do I make the storyboards within the framework customizable? i.e. people using my framework should be able to modify the storyboards to customize the look & feel.

When I imported my framework in another app project in XCode, I did not see the storyboard files within my framework. How to make them visible & editable?

Is it even advisable to use framework in this case or should I go with static library+resource bundles combination?

Comment: That's an interesting scenario. I think Storyboards are compiled, so you would have to distribute them outside, it would be more like distributing a template that uses the classes you have in your framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally did this,

- Load custom xibs,storyboards dynamically. i.e. first try loading custom storyboards, if not present load default storyboard(use try catch to check).
- Expose all viewcontroller outlets and event handling functions through header files.
- Make connections between buttons in your custom framework and these header file outlets,event handlers. Done! Your Viewcontroller.m functions will be called on clicking on those buttons.

Comment: Can you pls share an example of this? Am looking for something similar.